# How do you remove characters in parentheses for multiple files on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, rename, file-rename, automator

I want to remove the parentheses from the names of over 1000 file on Mac. So I want to rename the files labelled *Jessica (Love)* to ***Jessica***, *(9999)James(333)* to ***James***, and so on. I'm unfamiliar with Terminal and Automator so if it requires either please walk me through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using the terminal.
Steps:

1. Open the Terminal app (Cmd+Space -> type terminal -> press 'return' key)
2. Change directory to the folder containing your files.
   Eg: `cd /path/to/files`.
   Note: You can drag and drop the folder into Terminal to get it's path
3. Type the following lines in the terminal

```
for file in *; 
do
    mv $file $(echo $file | sed -E 's|\([^\(]*\)||g')
done
```

This iterates through all the files names, and issues a move (rename) command. Using regex, we can match the text inside the parenthesis.

Before:

```
(9999)James(333)
Jessica (Love)
```

After:

```
James
Jessica
```